# Cassandra : DELETE doesn't work

Tags: cassandra, row, cql

I have a table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE ab(group int,timestamp varchar,ab_id uuid, PRIMARY KEY (group,timestamp,ab_id)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC);
```

layout:

```
1 | 2015-04-01 08:48:46 | 07d2a30d-79f3-5619-bbdd-6e5140a68ec3
1 | 2015-04-01 08:47:24 | 08d3a40c-85c7-5823-ddcc-7e6174d78dg4
1 | 2015-04-01 08:46:33 | c35dedeb-3144-5818-c282-53cd7ee1e8e8
```

I can use insert and select queries but I can't delete a row.
I must use all primary keys because DELETE is reserved so I tried :

```
 DELETE FROM ab WHERE ab_id=2d1ddf9a-2e80-41ea-b891-e322edfb905e  AND "timestamp"='2015-04-02 03:29:54' AND group = 1;
```

But nothing happened, no message error and no row deleted ... ??

Comment: So when you do a select it gives you results?  select * FROM ab WHERE ab_id=2d1ddf9a-2e80-41ea-b891-e322edfb905e  AND "timestamp"='2015-04-02 03:29:54' AND group = 1;

Comment: @lordkain is asking you to check whether you have any data there.  Your `DELETE` statement looks fine.

Comment: is there more than one node in your cluster?

Comment: there is only one node

Comment: @lordkain : when I do the select statement like the delete statement, it gives me (0 rows).
I can use a select statement if I create index on a column and do a select * from this column with allow filtering.

Comment: there is youre "problem". delete statement works fine, but there is nothing to delete with youre where clause. try to select rows and first do a where on ab_id and see if you have results. then add another like timestamp .. then you will see where is the "error"

Comment: When I try this (select * from ab where ab_id = xxxx), it says that I must enter the primary key timestamp, and when I do this, it says the same with the primary key group, and when I do this he found nothing and delete nothing

Answer (score 1):

> when I do the select statement like the delete statement, it gives me (0 rows).

Which (as LordKain indicated) means that if you have nothing to `SELECT` then you won't have anything to `DELETE`, either.

> I can use a select statement if I create index on a column and do select * from this column with allow filtering

**DO NOT DO THIS.**  In several query-related questions that I have answered here lately, there seems to be many out there who think that queries with `ALLOW FILTERING` are a good idea.  These same users are typically back in a week or so, wondering why their `ALLOW FILTERING` queries suddenly are timing-out with more data.  Asking for `ALLOW FILTERING` is Cassandra's way of telling you that you are trying something which you probably should not be.

Additionally, secondary indexes are **NOT** your friend.  They were created for convenience, not for performance.  Some have even identified their use as an anti-pattern.

Cassandra was designed to be queried by specific keys in a specific order.  If your table does not suit your query, then you need to build an additional table that does.  This will allow you to perform your queries without `ALLOW FILTERING` or secondary indexes.

> When I try this (select * from ab where ab_id = xxxx), it says that I must enter the primary key timestamp, and when I do this, it says the same with the primary key group, and when I do this he found nothing and delete nothing.

That's because `DELETE` operations require specific, complete PRIMARY KEYs.  In your case, this should work:

```
DELETE FROM ab WHERE group=1 AND timestamp='2015-04-01 08:48:46' 
    AND ab_id=07d2a30d-79f3-5619-bbdd-6e5140a68ec3;
```

Your `DELETE` will not work if you are missing one or more of your PRIMARY KEY components.  Herein lies the drawback of designating every column in the table as a part of the PRIMARY KEY.  When you delete the row, you will need to specify them all.

The exception to that rule is you can DELETE by specifying a complete partition key.  So in your case this should work:

```
DELETE FROM ab WHERE group=1;
```

Of course, that will DELETE all rows under the `group` partition key of 1, so that may not be what you want.

The bottom line, is that Cassandra PRIMARY KEYs do not behave like RDBMs PRIMARY KEYs do.  As such, you cannot build your Cassandra data models with an RDBMS mindset.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in similar kind of situation before. When we do a,

```
SELECT * FROM ab;
```

you might have see something like,

```
group |      timestamp      |              ab_id
   1  | 2015-04-01 08:48:46 | 07d2a30d-79f3-5619-bbdd-6e5140a68ec3
   1  | 2015-04-01 08:47:24 | 08d3a40c-85c7-5823-ddcc-7e6174d78dg4
   1  | 2015-04-01 08:46:33 | c35dedeb-3144-5818-c282-53cd7ee1e8e8
   1  | 2015-04-02 03:29:54 | 2d1ddf9a-2e80-41ea-b891-e322edfb905e  <- Pay attention on this one
```

and when we query something like,

```
 SELECT * FROM ab WHERE group = 1 AND "timestamp"='2015-04-02 03:29:54' AND ab_id=2d1ddf9a-2e80-41ea-b891-e322edfb905e;
```

you might have see something like,

```
group |      timestamp      |              ab_id
      |                     |                                       <- Cannot see it!
```

But when we query like this,

```
SELECT * FROM ab WHERE group = 1 AND timestamp >'2015-04-02 03:29:54';
```

you will get,

```
group |      timestamp      |              ab_id
   1  | 2015-04-02 03:29:54 | 2d1ddf9a-2e80-41ea-b891-e322edfb905e  <- Pay attention on this one
```

That's because, even though `CQLSH` shows that out timestamp is `2015-04-02 03:29:54` the actual data that has been stored will look something like this `2015-04-02 03:29:54.156`

There are two ways to find out (maybe more?).

1. If you are on older version of Apache Cassandra/DSE, you can use `cassandra-cli`
2. If you are using a newer version where the above tool is depreciated, you can use Apache Spark and spark-cassandra-connector

I was using DSE and so I quickly created a SparkDF and then queried to find out.